# $dialog injection deprecated in v1.0.8

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angular and have inherited a project so apologies in advance if this is a basic/bad question. I have a controller

```
.controller('myCtrl', function($dialog) {}
```

thats causing the error

```
Error: Unknown provider: $dialogProvider <- $dialog
```

on another machine with angular 1.0.7 $dialog seems to originate from angular ui-bootstrap.js but is gone from 1.0.8. If this feature is deprecated does anyone have a suggestion of how to replace it?

Thanks in advance

C

Comment: Download the angular-ui module and use ui-bootstrap, then you can keep using $dialog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that we are speaking about the `$dialog` service from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ than the `$dialog` service (and hence your error) has absolutely nothing to do with the AngularJS version.

In the http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ the version 0.6.0 of the library brought complete rewrite of the `$dialog` service. During the rewrite it was renamed to `$modal` and its API has change in the non-backward-compatible way (although $modal and $dialog APIs are still pretty close so migration shouldn't be too painful).

So, what I presume is that you've updated to the latest angular-ui/bootstrap version (0.6.0) and this is why you are seeing this error. To get rid of it either downgrade to 0.5.0 or change your calls to use the new $modal service.